# Can I VNC directly into my "Linux Deploy" from OS X?

Tags: linux, osx, chroot, android, vnc

I use [Linux Deploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy) to run desktop Linux distributions on my Android devices. The way it works is the I start the system in the LD app, and then I go to [VNC Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android)  on the same device to get a GUI.

Now, suppose if I wanted to access this same Linux installation from my laptop (OS X). Could I use a VNC client to connect directly from there?

I **don't** mean having a second VNC connecting from Android to OS X.

I mean connecting the VNC hosted by Linux Deploy directly to a recipient client on OS X.

Is it possible to do it via a USB cable? And is that faster than connecting both the Android device and the laptop to the same WiFi network?

Is it possible to host a hotspot with the Android device, connect the laptop to it and then do VNC over that?

Obviously the connection should happen locally, not over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it worked out of the box. I hosted a hotspot with my phone, connected my laptop to that WiFi, and the VNC client on OS X could connect just like that.